# Diff used with anonumous pipes gives strange error when it is put in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, pipe, diff

I try to run 'diff' in Makefile, using anonymous pipes. Different results 
are observed comparing launching 'diff' from bash shell and from Makefile. Any clarification ? Thanks.

```
$ diff <(echo cat) <(echo dog)
1c1
< cat
---
> dog

$ make
diff <(echo cat) <(echo dog)
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `diff <(echo cat) <(echo dog)'
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

My Makefile is

```
test:
        diff <(echo cat) <(echo dog)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the error messages, your shell is `sh` not `bash`; so you cannot use Bash syntax features.

A common workaround is to set `SHELL=/bin/bash` (or your local equivalent) or, of course, refactor your code into POSIX-compliant shell script.

Comment: How would you write that line into POSIX-compliant script?

Comment: Trivially, temporary files. There may be more sophisticated workarounds, but I guess your example isn't really representative of your real-life problem, so it's hard to guess what your real boundaries are.